# Flutter enabled and focus textformfield

Tags: flutter

I create a profile page and i have 4 textformfield. I want to on tap icon activate textformfield and focus at the same time. Now I need tap twice on icon and first activated field, secondly focused.
How to solve it? 
My code:

```
 class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserProfileState createState() => _UserProfileState();
}

class _UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {
  FocusNode myFocusNode;
  bool isEnable = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40.0, 50.0, 20.0, 0.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    enabled: isEnable,
                    focusNode: myFocusNode,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isEnable = true;
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode);
                      });
                    })
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use     `autofocus: isEnable` instead.

Answer (score 0):

just do like below in your ontap

```dart
setState(() {
      if(isEnable)
         Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), ()
             {FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode);
         });
      isEnable = true;
    });
```

in first time isEnable is false so focusing not call and just enabling work and in other times get focus too.
you can't focus widget until disabled and when you enabling widget. when you do focusing and enabling at same time in ui tread it's try focusing before enabling because of their rendering time.if you post some delay to focusing the problem get solving.

Comment: It not work, I still need tap twice to activate and focuse. but need tap once to  activate and focuse.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `readOnly` instead of `enabled` in `TextFormField`

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when I had multiple `TextField`s to enable kinda `PIN` input. And some of that had to be dynamically enabled and disabled plus prevent users from entering value in the next field while they haven't finished the previous one. I've tried a lot of approaches and focusing field after some delay was not a way to go because I wanted the keyboard to always be available while entering. So I've took a crazy path and solved this next way:

`onTap: () => _focusNodes[_currentLetterIndex].requestFocus()`

where `_focusNodes` are for each letter and `_currentLetterIndex` is calculated programmatically during input (when finished letter 0 -> current becomes 1 and so on). As the result when user tried to tap on next field - it was automatically refocused to the current one which behaves like the next field is disabled.

An example of the full text field looks like this (don't pay attention to decorations etc.)

```dart
TextField(
  key: ValueKey(index),
  controller: _editingControllers[index],
  onTap: () => _focusNodes[_currentLetterIndex].requestFocus(),
  focusNode: _focusNodes[index],
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  showCursor: false,
  maxLength: 2,
  enableInteractiveSelection: false,
  autocorrect: false,
  enableSuggestions: false,
  style: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      height: 1.2,
      decoration: TextDecoration.none),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      fillColor: !_wordCompleted &&
              !correct &&
              _editingControllers[index].text.isNotEmpty
          ? const Color(0xFFFFEEF0)
          : Colors.white,
      filled: !correct,
      counterText: "",
      border: defaultInputBorder,
      focusedBorder: !correct &&
              !_wordCompleted &&
              _editingControllers[index].text.isNotEmpty
          ? incorrectInputBorder
          : focusedInputBorder,
      enabledBorder: _wordCompleted
          ? focusedInputBorder
          : correct
              ? correctInputBorder
              : defaultInputBorder,
      errorBorder: defaultInputBorder,
      disabledBorder: _wordCompleted
          ? focusedInputBorder
          : correct
              ? correctInputBorder
              : defaultInputBorder,
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2)),
),
```